# Filtering dataframe based on column value_counts (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying out pandas for the first time. I have a dataframe with two columns: `user_id` and `string`. Each user_id may have several strings, thus showing up in the dataframe multiple times. I want to derive another dataframe from this; one where only those `user_ids` are listed that have at least 2 or more `strings` associated to them.

I tried `df[df['user_id'].value_counts()> 1]`, which I thought was the standard way to do this, but it yields `IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series key provided`. Can someone clear out my concept and provide the correct alternative?

Comment: Related and probable dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30485151/python-pandas-exclude-rows-below-a-certain-frequency-count

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you need [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), because need same `index` of mask as `df`. But if use `value_counts` `index` is changed and it raise error.

```
df[df.groupby('user_id')['user_id'].transform('size') > 1]
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by mask?

Comment: mask is condition like `df['user_id'].value_counts()> 1`

Comment: A "mask" is basically a list of true or false values for a certain condition. Masks are normally used to subset data. Say you had a dataframe of dogs' names and ages, and you wanted only to look at dogs older than 5 years. A mask basically tests whether each row (each dog) is older than five years and returns a true-false-laiden series.

Comment: @not_a_robot - Thank you very much for comment.

Comment: @ZakS - Need define columns after groupby `test_filtered1 = test_filtered[test_filtered.groupby('disposition')['disposition'].transform('size')>100]`

Answer (score 0):

**You can simply do the following,**

```
col = 'column_name'   # name of the column that you consider
n = 10                # how many occurrences expected to be appeared

df = df[df.groupby(col)[col].transform('count').ge(n)]
```

this should filter the dataframe as you need

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge and used:

```
df['user_id'].value_counts()[df['user_id'].value_counts() > 1]
```

Credits: blog.softhints

Answer (score -1):

l2 = ((df.val1.loc[df.val== 'Best'].value_counts().sort_index()/df.val1.loc[df.val.isin(l11)].value_counts().sort_index())).loc[lambda x : x>0.5].index.tolist()